# How to hide Insert form of gridview when inserting row?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, devexpress

I am trying to insert a row in Gridview by using a button and text box outside of the  Gridview, and it is working fine. But whenever I am inserting the row, insert form of Gridview is appearing. How to disable this form?

my button:

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MenuAssignmentGv.AddNewRow();

    }
```

my datasource

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="AttdMenuAssignmentDs" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>' ProviderName='<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>'
        SelectCommand="select mra.RoleAssignmentID, mra.MenuRoleID ,  mr.MenuRole, mn.MenuName, mn.MenuUrl
    from ATTD_MST_MENU mn
    inner join ATTD_MST_MENU_ROLE_ASSIGNMENT mra
    on mn.MenuID=mra.MenuID
    inner join ATTD_MST_MENU_ROLE mr
    on mra.MenuRoleID=mr.MenuRoleID
    where mra.MenuRoleID=@MenuRoleID"
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO ATTD_MST_MENU_ROLE_ASSIGNMENT(MenuRoleID, MenuID) VALUES (@MenuRoleID, @MenuID)"

        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlRole" PropertyName="Value" Name="MenuRoleID" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlMenu" PropertyName="Value" Name="MenuID" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlRole" PropertyName="Value" Name="MenuRoleID"></asp:ControlParameter>
        </SelectParameters>

    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

whenever i click the button the form always appear, and then the record inserted after I click Update of that form.[form appear when inserting new row by clicking button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWYWa.jpg)

Comment: already added..

Comment: I'd suggest to use Gridview only to show data. You can write Insert/edit form code by your own.

Comment: Can you show your gridview and gridview events code? The information provided is not enough to help you

Answer (score 1):

The ASPxGridView.AddNewRow method does exactly what it should do according to the [documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridView_AddNewRowtopic):

> The AddNewRow method switches the ASPxGridView to edit mode and allows
>   the values of the new row to be edited.

Your task is different - you want to add the new row to the database and make it visible in the ASPxGridView. If you insert a new row to the database before the ASPxGridView.DataBind method is called, the new row will become visible in the ASPxGridView automatically. Alternatively, you can continue using the ASPxGridView API according to the documentation:

> To add the new record to the underlying datasource, call the
>   [UpdateEdit](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridView_UpdateEdittopic) method. To initialize row values in code, handle the
>   [InitNewRow](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridView_InitNewRowtopic) event.